# Where does an answer that is flagged as NAA and converted to a comment go?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, convert-to-comment

It says it was converted to a comment, but if you view the page, it doesn't show up as a comment....

[model has_many users(of a specific role type)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698575/model-has-many-usersof-a-specific-role-type/16713295#16713295)

But the answer has already been converted, and is visible only to me, and not in incognito mode

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: For example...?

Comment: There are several comments from you on that page, unless you provide us the text of the answer you think is missing we can't tell you if it's there or not

Comment: Yes. It is converted to comment on the question, but it is truncated.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is much too large to fit into the comment field, so it got truncated.

The comment is there, just under the question, looking very much out of place.

I will take it out of its misery and delete it all together, as it serves no purpose.

Comment: how to provide the information as feedback, as the answer isn't fully complete?   another SO question?

Comment: I think the moderator who converted it to a comment meant to convert it to an edit instead...

Comment: @chrisFrisina - If you have a **full** answer, you can post that. Feedback? Post a comment. If you have a **new** question, then yes, a new one.